# Why I have not any google analytics data and why does the consent initializer mode keeps "denied"?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The problem is that I have no data comming in Google Analytics since I setted up the consend banner
[no data inside GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRlOj.png)

Also, When I go the google tag manager debugger, I have no Consent Initialization 'granted' even after I accept the consent banner. Why ?

[No consent initialization granted captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt2RQ.png)

I note that I use Google Tag Manager tag inside the website and so I added inside tag manager tags tab the ID of google analytics account..

Here is the code of what I tried to do

And I expect to have google analytics data inside google analytics backoffice and also I expect that consent initlalization work...

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('consentMode') === null) {
        gtag("consent", "default", {
            "analytics_storage": "denied",
                      "ad_storage": "denied",
        });
    } else {
        gtag("consent", "default", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("consentMode")));
    }
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script> <!--- I replaced XXX by my real google tag manager key dont worry about it -->
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<script>
// Function to send consent to Google Analytics via GTM
  function sendConsentToGA(consent) {
        gtag('consent', 'update', {
            'analytics_storage': consent,
                        'ad_storage': consent
        });
                dataLayer.push({event: "gtm.click", consent});
                dataLayer.push({event: "gtm.linkClick", consent});
                dataLayer.push({event: "gtm.dom", consent});
                dataLayer.push({event: "gtm.load", consent});
    }
    
    window.onload = function() {
        
        if (localStorage.getItem('consentMode') == '"granted"') {
            sendConsentToGA("granted");
        }
        
        if (document.getElementById('btn_yes') != null) {
               // Listen for a click on the Elementor button
                    document.getElementById('btn_yes').addEventListener('click', function() {
                    // Get the consent value based on your logic
                        var consent = 'granted';
                        sendConsentToGA(consent);
                        gtag('consent', 'update', consent);
                        localStorage.setItem('consentMode', JSON.stringify(consent));
                    });

                    document.getElementById('btn_no').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        // Get the consent value based on your logic
                        var consent = 'denied';

                        // Send consent to Google Analytics via GTM
                        sendConsentToGA(consent);
                        gtag('consent', 'update', consent);
                        localStorage.setItem('consentMode', JSON.stringify(consent));
                    });
        }
    }
 
</script>
```